# How do I number nested fields?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I'm building nested fields with a `has_many`, `belongs_to` relationship like so:

`app/controllers/widgets_controller.rb`

```
def new
  @widget = Widget.new
  3.times { @widget.gizmos.build }
end
```

---

`app/views/widgets/_form.html.erb`

```
<%= form_for @widget do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.fields_for :gizmos do |b| %>
    <%= render 'gizmo_fields', f: b %>
  <% end -%>
  ...
<% end -%>
```

---

`app/views/widgets/_gizmo_fields.html.erb`

```
<%= f.label :name "Gizmo -NUMBER-" %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
```

---

How can I programatically determine the number `gizmo` out of the total number of `widget.gizmos`. Such that each the output would look like:

```
Gizmo 1 |_____text_____|
Gizmo 2 |_____text_____|
Gizmo 3 |_____text_____|
```

What I would like to avoid:

- **Using Javascript** - I know I can number these with vanilla javascript or jquery. I would like a pure ruby/rails solution so that not only would the code be easier to follow, but I hope to learn more about nested fields.
- **Incrementing a variable** - Again, I'd like to learn more about the context of nested fields and see if there is a more dynamic and concrete way to number the nested fields.

What I already know:

- I can access the current instance of `gizmo` through `f.object`
- I cannot access `f.object.widget` on the `new` action, because the records are not yet saved

Answer (score 1):

Well, I suppose I was close. I had all the pieces, just had to put them together. Since I could access the formbuilder's object, I could find its place in the array of its association to the `@widget`

```
<%= f.fields_for :gizmos do |b| %>
  <%= render 'gizmo_fields', f: b, index: @widget.gizmos.index(b.object) + 1 %>
<% end -%>
```

---

`app/views/widgets/_gizmo_fields.html.erb`

```
<%= f.label :name "Gizmo #{index}" %>
<%= f.text_field :name %>
```

Answer (score 0):

i believe there is a variable available in your partial that is 'PARTIAL_NAME_counter', i.e.

```
gizmo_fields_counter
```

see http://databasically.com/2009/04/09/rails-render-partial-counters-displaying-a-records-index/

Comment: Hm... no such luck... The article seems a bit dated.